# Простой пример шифрования любого файла на Delphi

Tags: delphi, шифрование

Всем привет!

Прошу привести пример простого шифрования файлов на delphi. Необходимо шифровать некоторые файлы. Решил написать консольную прогу для этой цели, но вот только с шифрованием никогда не сталкивался.

Итак, на входе программы надо иметь путь к файлу и ключ. Может еще что-то упустил? На выходе полностью измененный исходный файл, без возможности прочтения, чтоб внутри была всякая абра-кадабра.

Какой тип файлов надо будет шифровать, заведомо неизвестно, может jpg, а может exe или даже py.

**Вывод:**  пожалуйста, дайте какой-нибудь подробненький исходник с коментами. Спасибо.

Comment: Как то слишком много запросов для простого вопроса, не находите ? ;)

`XOR` вам в руки, самый просто способ шифрования

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, всё зависит от того, какой сложности тебе нужен шифр. Самый простой способ - это берёшь ключ и поблочно выполняешь операцию `XOR` с файлом (размер блока = размеру ключа). Для расшифровки достаточно выполнить `XOR` ещё раз, и файл будет иметь прежний вид.
Если что-нибудь посложнее нужно, то тоже большой выбор, например `DES`, `3DES`, `AES`. Наверняка, есть готовые библиотеки под них.

Вот ещё ссылку посмотри, может это оно: [DCPcrypt — криптография в Delphi](http://forum.vingrad.ru/articles/topic-219951/kw-dcpcrypt-delphi-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84.html).

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать консольную утилиту 7zip. Её можно включать в дистрибутив любых программ. Просто архивируйте с ключом вместо пароля и не усложняйте себе жизнь.

Как вариант, если, конечно, важен результат с минимальными затратами, а не сам факт написания;)